# How to find the aggregate total sum of debit - sum of credit and group in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL Table with the following rows. I am trying to find the aggregate sum of each book_name with the formula, (sum of debit- sum of credit).

Thus this is the table,

```
book_name transaction_type  amount
demo       credit            20
demo       debit             100
testing    credit            10
testing    debit             30
```

This is the result I want.

```
demo -80
testing -20
```

How do I do this query in MySQL? I have been trying various syntaxes and solutions but none seem to work.

Comment: You should edit your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it. I always had a wrong syntax. This helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select book_name, sum(case when transaction_type = 'credit' then amount else - amount end)
from t
where transaction_type in ('credit', 'debit')
group by book_name;
```